# Xcode download db from server

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am creating an app that uses a db to show data, but currently the db read it locally via FMDB. What I want to know is how can I download the db directly from a server and display it in the table view ?

Code snippet:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Climbing" ofType:@"db"];

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Error Opening DB");
        return;
    }
    NSString *queryString;
    CDData *regioni;

    queryString = @"SELECT * , (SELECT count (*) FROM citta t WHERE t.id_regione = a.id_regione) as city FROM regione a ";

    FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:queryString];
    while ([s next]) {
        regioni = [[CDData alloc] initWithRecordSet:s];
        [self.data addObject:regioni];

    }
    [db close];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a download task using URL session:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://server_DB_URL_here";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
```

Then use the delegate implementation once the download task is finished to move the DB file in it's place:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                              didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location;
```

Then use your code you posted to open DB from the saved path.

```
   FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:....
```

Side Note: I wouldn't do all of the above in viewWillAppear: